# Are candlestick and OHLC charts useful for fundamental investors?

Tags: stocks, value-investing, chart

When investing based on fundamentals, I usually look at simple line charts to get an idea of the trading range for stocks (e.g. 1 year or 5 year trading range). I noticed that there are fancier chart types out there. For example, open-high-low-close (OHLC) charts and candlestick charts. Are these fancy charts useful for fundamental investors in any way? If so, how?